# How to increase character level

Tags: inflation-rpg

I character levels keep saying 0.  I can't figure out how to get them higher even though I've gotten to about level 8000 so far.  How do I increase this?

Bonus: What do the 'Play Gems' do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character levels are granted whenever you finish a game.  Once the character hits a total amount of levels across multiple playthroughs, they gain a character level.  Those levels are:

> Level 1: 50,000 levels
>       Level 2: 450,000 levels
>       Level 3: 1,600,000 levels
>       Level 4: 4,200,000 levels
>       Level 5: 9,000,000 levels

The chart is pulled from [here](http://inflation-rpg.wikia.com/wiki/Basics#Abilities), bottom of the page.  There doesn't seem to be much point in obscuring the value with an XP modifier, so I re-worded it to just point at total levels.